# How to use list view to add records to a Junction Object

Tags: apex, list-view, junction-object

I'm trying to create an apex page to allow users to multi-select objects (Property) and relate them to another object (Property Group) by populating a junction object (Property Group Member).

[image: Property Data Model]

Because there will be thousands of Property__c, I'd like to be able to leverage the existing listview and it's filters to be able to easily pick 10's or 100's at a time and add them to the Property_Group (e.g. creating instances of the Junction object).

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Property_Group__c" extensions="PropertyGroupExtention">
   <apex:detail showChatter="false" title="true" relatedList="false" />
   <apex:relatedList list="Property_Group_Members__r" title="Selected Member Properties" id="memberProperties" />

    <apex:PageBlock title="Available Properties" id="available">
        <apex:listViews type="Property__c" id="availableProperties"/>
    </apex:PageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

I have added a custom page, custom SetController, and tied them to the listview using a Custom Listview Button "Add Available Properties".

```
<apex:page standardController="Property__c" extensions="PropertiesController" recordSetVar="properties" >
   <apex:form >
       <apex:pageBlock title="Add Selected Properties to Property Group">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
           <apex:commandButton action="{! addToPropertyGroup}" value="Confirm"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selected}" var="prop">
                <apex:column value="{!prop.name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!prop.Status__c}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

My custom controller here:

public with sharing class PropertiesController 
{
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController;

```
public Id propertyGroupId {get;set;}

public PropertiesController(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController)
{
    this.standardController = standardController;
}

public PageReference addToPropertyGroup()
{       
    List<Property__c> selectedProperties = (List<Property__c>) standardController.getSelected();

    if (selectedProperties.size() == 0) return null; // do nothing

    propertyGroupId = getIdFromPage();

    System.debug('PropertyGroup ID: '+ propertyGroupId);

    if (propertyGroupId == null) { 
        System.debug('PropertyGroupId was null and is required!');
     }


    Set<Id> existingIds = createSetOfExistingMembers();

    // Create a List of NET-new properties_group_members to add
    List<Property_Group_Member__c> newMembersToBeAdded = new List<Property_Group_Member__c>();   
    for(Property__c current : selectedProperties)
    {
       System.debug('Property: ' + current.id + ' was selected');

       if (!existingIds.contains(current.id)) {
          System.debug('adding ' + current.id + ' to group ' + propertyGroupId);
          String theName=propertyGroupId + '.' + current.Id;
          newMembersToBeAdded.add(new Property_Group_Member__c(Name=theName, Property__c=current.Id, Property_Group__c=propertyGroupId, Unique_Name__c=theName));
       } else {
           System.debug('skipping ' + current.id + ' exists in group already');
       }
    }
    if (newMembersToBeAdded.size() > 0) {
       System.debug('Adding ' + newMembersToBeAdded.size() + ' properties');
       insert newMembersToBeAdded;
    } else {
       System.debug('Nothing to add!');
    }   

    return  new PageReference(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL'));
}

private Set<Id> createSetOfExistingMembers() {
    // Fetch the Existing  Members so we can avoid problems of adding Duplicates
    Set<Id> existing = new Set<Id>();
    for (List<Property_Group_Member__c> existingMembersChunk : [SELECT Property__c FROM Property_Group_Member__c WHERE Property_Group__c = :propertyGroupId]) {
       for (Property_Group_Member__c current:  existingMembersChunk) {
          System.debug('Existing: ' + current.property__c + '');
          existing.add(current.property__c);
       }
    }
    return existing;
}

private String getIdFromPage() {
   PageReference returnURLPage = new PageReference(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL'));
   return returnURLPage.getParameters().get('id');
}
```

}

I'm unstuck at this point, but my approach to passing context seems really hacky, I can't seem to pass any context from the original page cleanly (e.g. the currently selected PropertyGroup) -- the only available context is the retURL.  Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: I see nothing in your code that would call a controller, create a list, perform any action, etc. did you fail to post all of your code or not sure where to start?

Comment: @Eric I've updated with the rest of the source.  Since I originally posted this, I've made some progress, but it still feels like a hack to me.

Comment: Why are you returning a page reference? Make the return type void and add a serenader to your command button to refresh the part of your pages that displays the added items

Comment: Serenader?  PageRef is to force it back to the original page.  To my original question, is there a better pattern to follow to populate a junction entity? @Eric

Comment: rerender - dang autocorrect. Not sure really what you are trying to do, do you want to display the results on the page, goto a new page? If you just want to display the results you do not need to return a pagreference, simply do a partial page refresh